# Multiple forms on click ask for confirmation and submit that form

Tags: php, jquery

So I have a table that has a few entries. Each entry you can delete like so (this was the suggested way with using Laravel 5.2):

```
<form class="delete" action="//localhost:3000/admin/market-managers/11" method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">

    <button type="submit" class="delete-button"></button>

</form>

<div class="confirmation-buttons">
  <button class="confirm-button">Confirm</button> 
  <button class="cancel-button">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Right now that works great. But I want a "Confirm or Cancel" button set to pop up. So I wrote this:

```
$('.delete').on('submit', function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  var form = $(this);

  $(this).next('.confirmation-buttons').show();

  $('.cancel-button').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('.confirmation-buttons').hide();
  });

  $('.confirm-button').click(function() {
    form.submit();
  });

});
```

It works as in it shows, and if you cancel they hide, but if you confirm nothing happens.

Comment: There's nothing in the `.confirm-button` click handler that submits the form.

Comment: Since you have `event.preventDefault();`, the form will not submit. You need to submit the form after your checks: `form.submit()`

Comment: @Barmar I corrected the question. I changed it before to make sure it was targeting the right form and not all of them

Comment: @Shane I updated my question. I did have that originally when it wasnt working.

Comment: @Packy are these forms being generated after page load? what happens when you do `console.log(form)` in the `.confirm-button` click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're adding multiple `click` handlers to the confirm button. Every time you click on a form's submit button, it adds another click handler to the confirm button. Clicking the cancel button doesn't remove this, so when you eventually do click on the confirm button, it will run all the accumulated click handlers. They'll be run in the order that they were added, so it will submit the first form that the user submitted, even if they cancelled it. And since submitting a form reloads the page, the actual form they confirmed will not be submitted.

In general, it's wrong to add event handlers inside other event handlers. Don't add the click handler every time the user clicks on submit, just bind it once, using a global variable to remember the last form that they clicked the submit button on.

```
$(function() {
    var form;

    $('.cancel-button').click(function() {
        $(this).parent('.confirmation-buttons').hide();
        form = null;
    });

    $('.confirm-button').click(function() {
        if (form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });

    $('.delete').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        form = this;
        $(this).next('.confirmation-buttons').show();
    });
});
```

When setting `form`, use `this` rather than `$(this)` so that `form.submit()` will just run the standard Javascript submission function, not re-run the jQuery handler.

Or, instead of using `$('.delete').on('submit')`, you could use `$('.delete-button').on('click')`, and change the delete button to `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`.

Comment: That, and the .delete submit event was told to preventDefault again after form.submit();

Comment: That's supposed to happen. Clicking on the delete button isn't supposed to submit the form, it just shows the confirm and cancel buttons.

Comment: Yes, but the Anwser's example did call the submit() again. But when it was called (for the 2nd time) it was indeed (like you said) adding an other (duplicate) event. But that would still work if event.preventDefault was not used. That is the real reason why the 2nd submit call was ignored. But it is never a good idea to leak by creating duplicate event listeners

Comment: I don't think that's a problem. When you call `form.submit()`, there's no event, so `event.preventDefault()` has no effect.

Comment: OK, I've changed it so that it just runs `submit()` on the plain DOM element, not the jQuery object.